# How to install UHD device in redhawk using ubuntu 14.04

Tags: redhawksdr, usrp

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and i'm trying to install the UHD device from the github but i'm getting an error that won't allow it to build.

```
checking whether the Boost::System library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_system... yes
checking whether the Boost::Thread library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_thread... yes
checking whether the Boost::Regex library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_regex... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: executing depfiles commands
willie.thompson@seb215-wks07:~/redhawk/USRP_UHD/cpp$ make
  CXX      USRP_UHD-USRP_UHD.o
  CXX      USRP_UHD-USRP_UHD_base.o
  CXX      USRP_UHD-main.o
  CXX      USRP_UHD-template_impl.o
  CXXLD    USRP_UHD
/usr/bin/ld: USRP_UHD-USRP_UHD.o: undefined reference to symbol 'uuid_generate_random@@UUID_1.0'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [USRP_UHD] Error 1
seb215-wks07:~/redhawk/USRP_UHD/cpp$
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is the issue with Ubuntu?

Comment: I agree that the question is a little too broad.  That being said, I can at least point you in the right direction.  There is a USRP_UHD device that ships with the standard REDHAWK install. There are a few steps for using it: 1) Install the rpm (if you did not already install it with your base REDHAWK install). 2) Create and instantiate a Node that contains the device. 3) Allocate against the device. 4) Connect to the device.  Steps 2-4 are described in section 6.1.3 of the REDHAWK manual: https://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainch6.html#x8-1120006.1

Answer (score 0):

For now, you can edit the Makefile.am file to fix this.  At the end of the USRP_UHD_LDADD line, add -luuid, then you should be able to rebuild it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The version of g++ used in Ubuntu14 is stricter than the version used in CentOS6. Luckily, g++ is providing a good hint about what the issue is.

> /usr/bin/ld: USRP_UHD-USRP_UHD.o: undefined reference to symbol 'uuid_generate_random@@UUID_1.0'
>   //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

It is basically saying "What you want is here in libuuid.so.1 but you didn't put it on the command line so I'm refusing to use it".  While in CentOS6 g++ is less strict and links regardless, assuming that is what you wanted.

You have two options, one is the easy way out that works quick, one is a better long term solution:

1) Run make again in verbose mode, this will show you exactly what calls are being made and you can fix the offending call.  Lets do that below:

```
make V=1

< ... a bunch of calls to g++ that work fine or nothing if these have already run prior .... >

g++ -Wall -D__x86_64__ -D__linux__ -D__OSVERSION__=2 -DENABLE_EVENTS=1 -I/var/lib/redhawk/core/include -I/var/lib/redhawk/core/include/ossie -I/var/lib/redhawk/core/share/idl   -pthread -I/usr/include -I/var/lib/redhawk/core/include/frontend -I/var/lib/redhawk/core/include/redhawk -I/var/lib/redhawk/core/include/bulkio -I/var/lib/redhawk/core/include/ossie     -g -O2 -Wall   -o USRP_UHD USRP_UHD-USRP_UHD.o USRP_UHD-USRP_UHD_base.o USRP_UHD-main.o USRP_UHD-template_impl.o -L/var/lib/redhawk/core/lib64 -lossiecf -lossieidl -lCOS4 -lomniDynamic4 -lomniORB4 -lomnithread   -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_thread -lboost_regex -lboost_system -L/var/lib/redhawk/core/lib64 -lfrontend-2.2.0 -lfrontendInterfaces -lbulkio-1.10 -lbulkioInterfaces    -luhd   -llog4cxx  

/usr/bin/ld: USRP_UHD-USRP_UHD.o: undefined reference to symbol 'uuid_generate_random@@UUID_1.0'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [USRP_UHD] Error 1
```

Okay, so now we have the long ugly g++ call, we simply need to add "-luuid" to the list of linked libraries so we can tack that on at the end and voila! It will return without error.  Note that we simply hand ran 1 of the g++ calls so for good measure run Make again in case there are any additional build steps; in this case there are not, it will simply say "nothing to be done"

2) A better fix! So the build files clearly need some fixing.

If we take a look at the configure.ac we see that there are calls like this one:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([LIBUHD], [uhd >= 3.5.3])
```

What this is doing is saying "Check pkg-config for the module uhd, ensure it is of version >= 3.5.3 and store any build related info in a variables prefixed with LIBUHD so that I can use it later".  Sounds like what we want. We can check to see if pkg-config is aware of libuuid by viewing all of the packages it knows about:

```
pkg-config --list-all
```

That will show us everything pkg-config knows about and we see that it is aware of uuid.  So, lets add a line to configure.ac right below the check for the UHD driver and see what affect that has.  My line looks like this:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([LIBUUID], [uuid])
```

I put no version constraint.  Okay, so now in order for that change to be incorporated we need to rerun the reconf script and then we can see the configure output.

```
./reconf
./configure
<....a bunch of stuff....>
checking for LIBUUID... yes
<....a bunch more stuff....>
```

That's new! We are now checking for the uuid library in our configure call and if you take a look at the config.log file, new variables have been added:

> LIBUUID_CFLAGS='-I/usr/include/uuid  '
>   LIBUUID_LIBS='-luuid  '

Alright, almost there! Take a look at the Makefile.am file.  These variables are used there and dictate the calls to g++.  Append our newly made LIBUUID_CFLAGS and LIBUUID_LIBS variables to the end of the USRP_UHD_LDADD and USRP_UHD_CXXFLAGS variables like I've done below.

```
USRP_UHD_LDADD = $(PROJECTDEPS_LIBS) $(BOOST_LDFLAGS) $(BOOST_THREAD_LIB) $(BOOST_REGEX_LIB) $(BOOST_SYSTEM_LIB) $(INTERFACEDEPS_LIBS) $(redhawk_LDADD_auto) $(LIBUHD_LIBS) $(LIBUUID_LIBS)

USRP_UHD_CXXFLAGS = -Wall $(PROJECTDEPS_CFLAGS) $(BOOST_CPPFLAGS) $(INTERFACEDEPS_CFLAGS) $(redhawk_INCLUDES_auto) $(LIBUHD_FLAGS) $(LIBUUID_CFLAGS)
```

Since we've changed the Makefile.am files, we need to rerun ./configure.  Rule of thumb is that ./reconf creates your configure script from the configure.* files and ./configure creates the Makefile's from your Makefile.* files so if you edit a downstream file you need to rerun the upstream script.

Alright, now that we've done that things should work! We've added a system check for libuuid via pkg-config using the configure.ac file, stored the outcome in a variable and used that in our makefile template.

None of this is really unique to redhawk so if you'd like more information there is loads of documentation on the autotools build system and pkg-config.